# How can I get the formatting to apply to new form submissions?

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I want the formatting of columns G and H to look like G4 and H4 (for example), but the new form submissions are coming in looking like G7 and H7 (for example). How can I remedy this?

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T6TUzySQTLzjMni9ZyDWOFs6YnRqSwtzJ317ilJ0Y0Q/edit#gid=1507098520

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for font color, no-underline, and cell background color you need to use conditional formatting because submissions are added as new rows (not into existing rows)

for alignment of text try to select the whole column by clicking on column latter and format it as you wish